# c++ exception handling

Tags: c++, exception

Learning "try & catch". What is wrong with the following code?
Thanks for the advice.

Error in execution:

```
terminate called without an active exception
Aborted
```

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int a = 3;

  try
  {
    if (a < 5)
      throw;
  }
  catch (...)
  {
    printf ("captured\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: by the way your code looks more C_ish_ than C++_ish_ , just get used to code in C++ if you pick C++ as language of choice, this way your code can easily become a weird mix of languages without any benefit at all and can only make your life harder learning nothing new and useful. It's true that the C is supported under C++ without problems, but just try to have a simpler and much more linear approach when coding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside of a `try` block, you have to specify **what** to throw.  The only place you can use `throw` by itself is inside of a `catch` block to re-throw the current exception. If you call `throw` by itself without a current exception being active, you will kill your app, as you have already discovered.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main() 
{ 
  int a = 3; 

  try 
  { 
    if (a < 5) 
      throw 1; // throws an int 
  } 
  catch (...) 
  { 
    printf ("captured\n"); 
  } 

  return 0; 
}
```

You can `throw` anything you want, as long as you throw something.

Comment: It's a bit ambiguous to say '[you must use `throw` by itself inside of a `catch` block], because it suggests a syntactical limitation. In truth it's okay to rethrow whenever an exception is active -- regardless of scope.

Comment: @LucDanton: I did not say you must use `throw` by itself, I said the only place you can use `throw` by itself is inside a `catch`. There is no active exception if you are not inside a `catch`.

Comment: [A correct example where `throw;` is not syntactically used inside a `catch` block](http://liveworkspace.org/code/85bfc976aec21b24d65293ce9355b7cb).

Comment: The `throw` is not in a `catch` block directly, but it is being called in the context of a `catch` block.  That is fine.

Answer (score 5):

Your `throw;` statement tries to rethrow a current exception but there probably isn't one. You need something like

```
throw some_exception_object();
```

Comment: I'd recommend `throw std::runtime_error("message")`, but I have seen `throw 42` (which I believe can only be caught with `catch (...)`).

Comment: @MaxLybbert: It could be caught with `catch (int n)`, but yeah, throwing non-class types is not recommended for "real" programs.

Comment: Well, as far as recommendation for exceptions go, I'd recommend to only ever throw types derived from `std::exception` but probably actually being derived from one of the standard exceptions. That wasn't the question, though ;-)

Answer (score 4):

There are four things, two major and two minor. One thing at a time...

## 1. Rethrow usage w/o active exception

A `throw;` statement is used to re-throw an exception that is currently caught. For example:

```
try {
    do_something();
} catch (const std::exception &) {
    throw; // This statement re-throws an exception that was caught in this "catch" block.
}
```

In your case, you are using `throw;` without catching any exceptions (in order words — it does not appear inside `catch` block directly or indirectly), thus your program is terminated. When there is a need to throw and not to re-throw an exception, like in your case, you must specify an exception object to be thrown. For example:

```
throw std::runtime_error("Something bad happened");
```

## 2. catch-all clause which does not re-throw a caught exception

Your catch-all clause (`catch (...)`) is perfectly legal C++. However, it does not re-throw caught exception. Even though it is a legal C++ code, such a usage is a taboo. C and C++ runtime is usually using special types of exceptions to implement certain functionality. For example, [NPTL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_POSIX_Thread_Library) is using exceptions to implement a thread cancellation. If you catch that exception using `catch (...)`, a thread won't be cancelled and you are going to have a bad time. Generally, you have to catch exceptions by their types. In almost all cases, exceptions are inherited from `std::exception`, and so you have to write `catch (const std::exception &)` or, if you expect to catch an exact type, - `catch(const TypeYouExpect &)`. If you must, however, use catch-all, remember to re-throw. For example:

```
try {
    do_something();
} catch (...) {
    throw; // DO NOT FORGET TO RE-THROW.
}
```

## 3. Header naming...

You are including C header whereas C++ provides its own headers for standard C features. So, header:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

.. should be:

```
#include <cstdio>
```

C++ specific C functions get special treatment. For example, they become available in `std` namespace. So that you can use `std::open()` instead of just `open()` or `::open()`. No big deal, but is highly recommended way to go.

## 4. Return from main.

Unlike C, C++'s `main()` function is very special. It allows you not to have `return 0;`. This is a default behavior. So, unless you really need to return some value, you may save yourself some time by not typing `return 0;`. Remember, however, that `main` is the only function like that, and that everywhere else you must explicitly return something unless a function is marked `void`.

Hope it helps. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually throw some object. Even something as simple as

```
throw "error";
```

will catch the error like you want it to.

see it in action [here](http://ideone.com/0ykhv)

Answer (score 1):

The statement to throw an exception is:

```
throw <expression>;
```

This statement:

```
throw;
```

is also called the re-throw statement and is use to re-throw an existing exception that has been caught. It is typically used in a `catch` block, for example, you look at the exception and decide if you can continue, retry or abort. In case you decide to abort, you re-throw the exception so that somebody else down the call stack will catch it and handle this error.

For example:

```
// getResult() calls can fail with a deadlock exception
// This method will retry up to 3 times before failing
Result getResultWithRetry()
{
    int nbTry = 3;
    for(;;) {
        try {
            return getResult();
        } catch (DeadLockException& e) {
            if (nbTry == 0) {
                throw; // re-throw the deadlock exception
            }
        }
        --nbTry;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: catching exceptions by non-constant reference for no good reason is a bad practice. Unless you really need to modify the object, catch by constant reference. This allows compiler to perform more optimizations.